# A strange mismatch not noticed by Typescript. How is this possible?

Tags: node.js, typescript

Apparently, Typescript doesn't seem to recognize the difference between an object like `{}` and a generic array `[]` by accepting last one as input of a function that requires an object with `{}`'s structure.

To resume my problem, this is a simplified example to replicate it:

```
type test = { [key: string]: any };
let x: test = ["x", "y", "z"];
```

Actually, Typescript seems to accept this. How is this possible?

Note: The situation I ran into is more similar to this:

```
type fooType = { [key: string]: any };
const fooFunction<T extends fooType>(input: T) => // code...
fooFunction([]); // No red underline
```

But you can consider the first example. It's the same.

The main idea is to create a function that accepts only objects with a key (type string) and a value of any type.

Thank you in advance for the answers!

Comment: `{ [key: string]: any }` represents almost every object, including arrays, because arrays definitely have properties that are strings. By the way, yes, arrays are objects.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [TypeScript type that matches any object but not arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61148466/typescript-type-that-matches-any-object-but-not-arrays)

Comment: @Max I don't think this is the best question to link as a duplicate. They're using a function here, so they don't need a non-generic type, though the OP hints at how to do it with a generic type.

Comment: @vera linked issue is the exact issue OP has, the rest (function, generics) is a noise and can be stripped down without changing the problem. The whole problem is `type A = { [key:string]: any }; const a: A = [] // no error`, which is explained in the linked question

Answer (score 1):

Differentiating between plain objects and other things (like arrays, or even functions) can be frustrating in JavaScript (and therefore Typescript).

Since an array *is* an object, you need a type that *excludes* arrays. For completeness, you may also want to exclude other non-plain objects, like functions, dates, regexes, etc, but I'll just focus on arrays.

Using your example, here are some approaches:

### 1. Exclude objects with numeric indexes

```
function fooFunction<T extends {
  [key: string]: any,
  [index: number]: never
}>(input: T) { }
fooFunction(['']); // Will have red underline!
fooFunction([]); // This will NOT have an underline!
```

In the above case, we're saying that `T` cannot have any numeric indexes. There is an edge case, though: an empty array has type `never[]`, which also has no numeric indexes!

### 2. Exclude array-specific fields

Another approach is to identify some property common to arrays that won't be in any of the objects you plan to pass through your function:

```
function fooFunction<T extends {
  map?: never,
}>(input: T) { }
fooFunction(['']); // Will have red underline!
fooFunction([]); // So will this!
```

### 3. Narrow the parameter type

The cleanest approach is to narrow your generic at the parameter to exclude arrays. The following example uses a utility type that returns `never` for lots of non-plain-object inputs (but not all of them):

```
type FancyObject = any[]|Function|Date|RegExp|Error
type PlainObject<T> = T extends FancyObject
  ? never
  : T extends { [key: string]: any }
  ? T
  : never;
  
function fooFunction<T>(input: PlainObject<T>) {}
fooFunction(['']); // Will have red underline!
fooFunction([]); // So will this!
fooFunction({ hello: 'world' }) // This is fine!
```

Comment: Ok I adopted the third solution and I extended the FancyObject type to other object types too:
`type FancyObject =  any[] | boolean | number | string | Function | Date | RegExp | Error | null | undefined | Symbol | BigInt | Int8Array | Int16Array | Int32Array | Uint8Array | Uint16Array | Uint32Array | Uint8ClampedArray | Float32Array | Float64Array;`
Do you think that could be good?

Comment: @BurnAsIce Unfortunately you can't easily exhaust the list of non-plain objects, since you can also create custom classes whose instances you may or may not want to exclude. How extensive you need your exclusion list depends on your use case -- I typically use the *minimal* exclusions possible, opting to try to whitelist based on what I'm doing with the type.